# dhtmlx week view angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am trying to implement dhtmlx scheluder with angular which i able to implement successfully with this [post](https://dhtmlx.com/blog/angular-dhtmlxscheduler-tutorial/), but my concern is i want to so week days at y-axis and time at x-axis. I saw week view inside [timeline](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/sample_timeline.shtml) view and this is what i want to do but unfortunately this one is not working with angular and it's also available in pro version only.

So my question is there any work around to achieve it with out using timeline or pro version ?

Thanks, all answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to use the timeline view of dhtmlxScheduler, either that or implementing something from scratch

Since there are no npm packages of PRO versions of dhtmlx components, you have a couple of ways to add the professional version of dhtmlxscheduler to your project:

1) Add scheduler files to your project by hand - just copy scheduler files into a folder in your project and (e.g. `src/assets/scheduler`) import them from code `import './assets/scheduler/codebase/dhtmlxscheduler`).

2) If you have a private npm server, you can manually make a npm package from the scheduler codebase - enter the codebase folder of dhtmlxScheduler and run `npm init`, upload the package to your npm server and install it from there.

Related documentation article: https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/install_with_bower.html#addingproeditionintoproject

Comment: I have to purchase pro version for this ?

Comment: The feature you need is not available in the free version of the component, so yes, if you'll end up using dhtmlxScheduler for this, you'll have to buy it.
You can download a trial build to test whether it works for you https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/download.shtml  But if you'll end up using the Pro version of the component in your product, you'll need to buy a license